# Wordpress Website to store Geolocation of the users and search based on it

Tags: wordpress, geolocation

This is my first website development project and the requirement is to build a website with users database having the geolocation of the users stored. and when a new user signs up and searches for nearby users, I need to show all the nearby users based on the stored geolocations.
Is it possible to achieve this with Wordpress? I found one plugin which lets select the location but nothing for storing it and searching against it. Thanks.

Tried a plugin which lets user select and submit the geolocation but nothing for searching.